# jenkins, изменить статус билда в секции post

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Необходимо изменить состояние билда в зависимости от некоторых условий в секции post!

```
pipeline
{
    // stages...
    post
    {
        failure {
            node('awesome_node_label') {
                script {
                    if (variable_1 == false)
                    {
                        //остальные шаги
                        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При выполнении некоторых стадий на разных этапах может возникнуть ошибка. Необходимо попытаться восстановить состояние в конце пайплайна. Если восстановлено - результат указать как UNSTABLE, иначе оставить FAILURE.

Указанный пример не работает. Остальные шаги выполняются, строка с изменением результата билда не имеет эффекта. Jenkins 2.208

Comment: возможно не зря разработчики [советуют использовать](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218554077-how-to-set-current-build-result-in-pipeline) для установки статуса блок `try catch` (а не секцию `post`)

Comment: да, я тоже погуглил эту страничку. Но я не могу в каждой из секций сделать копипасту try catch, да и по логике восстановление состояния мне нужно делать в самом конце (если оно требуется). Для чего идеально подходит секция `post`

Comment: зачем же в каждой секции добавлять, если можно глобально обернуть? а если понадобятся для этого вложенные секции — [так они есть](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#sequential-stages). то, что для финальной обработки логически подходит секция post — это понятно. но вам-то надо изменить статус сборки, а не просто набор команд выполнить, и вы сами же пишете, что в секции post он у вас не изменяется (точнее, изменение не даёт эффекта).

Comment: Как должна выглядеть структура стадий, обёрнутая в `try catch` блок? Пока не вижу разницы между последовательными (вложенными) стадиями и последовательными "прямыми" стадиями. Прямые по текущей стратегии также отменяются если любая из предыдущих завершилась неудачей. а параллельные с опцией parallelsAlwaysFailFast сразу отменяются @aleksandrbarakin

Comment: попробуйте как в примере по первой ссылке.

Comment: `try catch` можно использовать только в шаге `script` в *declarative pipeline*. По первой ссылке пример для *scipted pipeline*, где каждая строчка интерпретируется как потенциальный код. Отсюда и корень моего вопроса. Ещё я понял что существует правило "только ухудшения" состояния билда. Из unstable нельзя вернуть в success, из failure нельзя вернуть в unstable.. задача усложняется. Вводить новый родительский для ручной обработки состояния билда кажется мне костылём.

Comment: в версии 2.16 были добавлены [параметры для catcherror](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#216). вот там можете изменить статус. а в секции post оставьте только обработку.